# Query webpages without downloading

Tags: html, unix

I have a huge list of webpages (around 1.8 million) in a file. I basically want to query each of these webpages for the character encoding used in them. I could have used wget, this will download the page and then I can grep for charset= pattern to get the encoding. But I don't want to download any of these pages, but just query the encoding. How can I do that? Please suggest me some other tool which is fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use python's `requests` library to do this pretty easily.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.head('http://www.google.com')
>>> r.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
```

Note the use of `head` vs `get` method (the latter will download the entire page).

You can also use the `-I` flag with curl to issue a `HEAD` request and `grep` for the "Content-Type" line:

```
jjensen@jjensen-dev:~$ curl -I www.google.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 16 Feb 2014 09:05:28 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=081cb517341de334:FF=0:TM=1392541528:LM=1392541528:S=O2_rr0DFBFW5RtJS; expires=Tue, 16-Feb-2016 09:05:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=Ouu0WjP7K0cdtuLZ1XTRdETnNTIRbf1DjfopTXoFAdC84DnrQ03OsABMx7QUFlRJ3pPrvkmO8-2nUmVfjjpEMLg-CNlh7wBLmuf5xrbJN-qmPVp7zhfS39q9xrjIOk8B; expires=Mon, 18-Aug-2014 09:05:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: I tried this but I get :

>>> import requests 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: You need to install the library first.

Comment: @Lanc you need to install the package with `pip install requests` or `easy_install requests`. You might also have to be sudo depending on your setup.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to install this as I don't have admin rights, some other alternatives?

Comment: Yes I checked, have curl

Comment: Then see my updated answer for a way to do this using `curl`.

Comment: But does curl have batch mode sort of thing? As I need to process millions of links, moreover I would have to store the headers of each link locally before I can grep each of them.

Comment: No you don't. Put all of the URL's in a text file on the machine, then do a simple bash for loop: `for u in \`cat urllist\`; do echo $u; curl -s -S -I $u | grep 'Content-Type'; done;` assuming the name of the file is `urllist`

Comment: But will not this be quite a bit slow?

Comment: You ultimately have millions of URL's to process. Since you're only issuing a HEAD request vs a GET request, you don't have to download the entire page, but you still have a lot of records to process. `curl` is written in C so it would naturally be faster than the python option. My only other suggestion would be to learn some advanced bash scripting to fork off batch jobs of this, but IMO it would be more trouble than it's worth to do something so simple.